# Natbib breaking wrapfig

Tags: natbib, wrapfigure

I am using `natbib` for citation and am encountering some problems with wrapfigures (or wraptables) which sit next to paragraphs starting with `natbib`s `\citet` or `\citep` (and probably other citation commands).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{ABC,
 year = {2006},
 title = {{ABC}},
 editor = {Parker, Peter}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{wrapfigure}{O}{5cm}
  \rule{4.5cm}{4.5cm}
\end{wrapfigure}

\citet{ABC} %uncomment and everything's fine
\lipsum[3]

\par\lipsum[3]\par\lipsum[3]\par\lipsum[3]

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

As soon as the paragraph does *not* start with `\cite...` everythin works as expected but in this case the paragraph starting with `\cite` will not wrap around the figure - the following pars then unnecessarily *do* wrap around nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of `\citet` could be more robust, it starts a group too early.

It works if you use

```
\mbox{}\citet{ABC}
```

so it doesn't formally start the paragraph.

Alternatively you can redefine `\citet` in your preamble after loading `natbib`

```
\edef\citet{\noexpand\leavevmode
            \noexpand\protect
            \expandafter\noexpand\csname citet \endcsname}
```

Then the `\mbox{}` is not needed.